# About MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. In every minute, the Table A will be inserted data by program.

I have set following trigger in Table A. The objective is to insert the newly data into Table B for backup.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `InsertTableA`;
CREATE DEFINER=`aa@localhost` TRIGGER `InsertTableA` AFTER INSERT ON `TableA` 
    FOR EACH ROW
        INSERT INTO `TableB` (`date`, `time`, `tempOut`) VALUES (new.date, new.time, new.tempOut)
```

In the Table B, I want to delete the old data in the Table A after new data added in the Table B.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `DeleteTableA`;
CREATE DEFINER=`aa@localhost` TRIGGER `DeleteTableA` AFTER INSERT ON `TableB`
    FOR EACH ROW
        delete from TableA where date < date(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 35 day))
```

However, for the Table B trigger, it cannot be implemented. But I can use following code to delete the Table A data:
delete from TableA where date < date(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 35 day))

I don't know what is the problem in it!

Comment: *"it cannot be implemented"* Why ? Are you getting any error message ?

Comment: `DeleteTableA` seems to be for maintenance rather than being a real trigger. I would suggest you to use an [`EVENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) rather, executed daily at a fixed hour

Comment: The hosting closed the super privilege, so that I cannot set up event.

Comment: You can maybe find a hacky way by doing a cron job that calls a stored procedure which performs the deletion

Comment: Thank you. I think corn job is a good idea. I will use corn job to implement the php.